# Is there is any difference between "full life" and "full of life" (without any context)?

Tags: adjectives

What is the difference between these?

> 1. Full of life
> 2. Full life

I have no context for them.

Comment: The context might be an oration or obituary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Full of life

This is an adjective phrase, in which the adjective *full* is modified by the preposition phrase *of life*. Just as a glass can be *full of wine*, or a box can be *full of toys*, a person or an animal can be said to be *full of life*, meaning that it exhibits much vitality or energy or exuberance.

This can also be employed figuratively of non-living things: we might say for instance that a painting is *full of life*.

> Full life

This is a noun phrase, in which the adjective *full* modifies the noun *life*. A *full life* might be *full* in many senses. If we say of a friend that she leads a *full life*, we may mean that she is engaged in many enjoyable or fulfilling activities, or simply that she is very busy. We might speak of a great artist's or statesman's *full life*, meaning her life beyond the activities which made her famous—her family life, her religious life, her love life. Or *full life* may mean simply *entire life*, as when we say that someone spent her *full life* in a particular place.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference. Without context, it's hard to know where to begin.

To start with, "full of life" is an adjective phrase; it needs to modify something.

> She was full of life.

while "full life" is a noun phrase:

> His full life left him satisfied.

In terms of meaning, to be "full of life" is more likely to refer to your attitude towards the world around you; it's about what you bring to the world.

On the other hand, to lead a "full life" is more about what the world holds for you; what you get from the world.

Comment: For some learners, it may be worth noting that an adjective phrase like "full of life" (one with post-head dependents) typically cannot occur attributively.  We can say "She was full of life" but not \*"She was a full of life person".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference.

> Full of life.

expresses that the subject is energetic, expressive, outgoing, happy, etc.

> Even though she's 89, Aunt Maude is still full of life.

-

> Full life.

describes someone's, presumable long, life where they made the most of their time, did many things, met a lot of people, etc.  There is a slight implication that their life has ended of is about to end.

> Aunt Gert is in poor health, but she's lived a full life so we should celebrate that.